# objective c - change to another navigationcontroller of viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

i have problem: there is an oriantable (rotatable) navigationcontroller with a viewcontroller. I want to change to a new navigationcontroller of viewcontroller, that is not orientable. 
I tried to change only the Viewcontroller with the old navigationcontroller, but in this case, the application was still rotatable.

Thanks for the help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redefine an other NavigationController and block the rotation you want. And when you want to push your view controller , call the other Navigation Controller.

```
YourCustomNavigationController *kiwappNav = [[YourCustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:kiwappNav animated:YES];
```

and your custom navigationController for example :

```
#pragma mark - Orientation
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
   switch ([Device getDeviceFormat])
  {
    case DF_IPAD:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        break;
    case DF_IPOD:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        break;
    default:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        break;
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you.